# RedirectMatch 403 -- Need to have an exception for 1 URL in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, regex

How do I allow "rpc.php" to get not redirected by this line in apache .htaccess

```
 RedirectMatch 403 /+(soap|cache|xtemplate|data|examples|include|log4php|metadata|modules)/+.*\.(php|tpl)
```

I got a couple options but not sure the best approach.

- Would a negative lookahead regex work?  I tried a couple variations with no luck.
- Perhaps there is a way to put an explicit allow either before or after the RedirectMatch

### Background

For those wondering why.  I'm developing for sugarcrm.  The application includes the line above in a .htaccess file for the entire web app.

I'm trying to allow rpc.php to enable a spellchecker in TinyMCE.

I'd have to signifigantly rewrite TinyMCE's spellchecker plugin to support the proper MVC way of doing this in SugarCRM which i'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
RedirectMatch 403 /+(soap|cache|xtemplate|data|examples|include|log4php|metadata|modules)/+((?!rpc).)*\.(php|tpl)
```

This should match stuff like `/soap/something.php` but NOT `/soap/rpc.php`

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  I was totally botching my regex.  ((?!rpc).)* is genius.  Thanks again.