# RedirectMatch RegEx — Need to have an exception

Tags: regex, apache, mod-alias

I have this RedirectMatch directive:

```
RedirectMatch 404 (.old|.csv|.txt|.sql|.ini)$
```

I now want to exlude robots.txt, but keep sending the 404 for all other .txt. How?

I fiddled with it looking at [RedirectMatch 403 -- Need to have an exception for 1 URL in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796687/redirectmatch-403-need-to-have-an-exception-for-1-url-in-htaccess) but I could not make it work.

Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negative look-behind

```
RedirectMatch 404 (.old|.csv|(?<!robots).txt|.sql|.ini)$
```

Comment: thank you for mentioning the term "negative look-behind", I will look it up